# webpage css show with blank after update server

Tags: javascript, html, css

This morning after I resize my server in digital ocean, my [website page](http://tiaopc.com/item/16) looks disordered with header auto drop down and a large area of blank after footer.
I didn't change code after the server update, but it seems that the `style.css` have some problem with page show.

I use safari and chrome to open the page, but got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some issues in your html, yours content added twice, the second one is added beneath all script tags.

Look to print screen that i've made (here you can clearly see that you have your content twice)

[image]

Hth. Good Luck !

Comment: I check the template of my framework. Seems that I include my header twice. Anyway, it solved.